# How do I know if an Android tablet supports Project Butter?

Tags: performance, touchscreen, user-interface

As far as I know, Project Butter is just shorthand for versions of Android OS that have quicker touch screen response, close to the "physicalness" of iOS devices.

But how do I know if a particular Android device has it?

Will a version of the OS with Project Butter (for example, Android 4.1) have silky-smooth touch response on ANY device it is installed on?

I'd like to use the answer to this question to buy a lot (20) identical tablets on ebay, so hopefully there is a way to answer the question for a particular device without having it in my hands.

Answer (score 6):

"Project Butter" is Google's name for the UI latency enhancements [implemented](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/27/3118769/android-4-1-jelly-bean/in/2885087) in Android 4.1 [Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html). Any Android device running Android 4.1 or later will have those enhancements.

Remember, though, that software is only part of what makes an interface smooth and 4.1 isn't a cure-all for lag. Slow hardware will result in a slow UI regardless of the OS. Your best bet is to find a tablet with 1) 4.1 or higher, 2) good specs, and 3) good reviews of its performance.

Comment: Nuts. So buying a random no-name tablet with 4.1 might have a laggy touchscreen...

Comment: Why "nuts"? A noname tab will probably be perfectly fine, if it's recent. Project Butter tries hard to give a smooth user experience. It obviously cannot do magic if the hardware is cheap/crappy. Trying out the device in advance, if you want to buy it is the answer here. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE

Comment: @ce4 I think "nuts" is being used here as a mild profanity, not in its "crazy" sense.

Comment: @DanHulme: Thanks for the clarification, non-native speaker here :-)

Comment: @user41634: unfortunately so. My 2012 Nexus 7 16GB, for example, is running the latest Android version 4.3.3. It can suffer from fairly extreme hang ups even with decent internals. I do love it but I wouldn't call it consistently smooth. YMMV of course which is why I think reading reviews is a big part of a buying decision.